# Droppable issue when I use axis property in draggable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am facing a problem in drag/drop while applying draggable as horizontally only.

I have created one div as draggable which can drag horizontally only. I am creating absolute div on drag start and put this drag clone(helper) inside that div so that this div can drag within that div only. Now If I am trying to move that div upwards then of-course it will not move, right. that is ok. so If I try to move it up then it will stay there but my mouse pointer will not be there inside div so I release my mouse pointer outside the droppable then its not working but If my mouse pointer is also within droppable div then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the mouseup event to the window.

```
$(window).mouseup(function() {
  $(YOUR_DIV).mouseup();
});
```